# What kind of authorization I should use for my facebook application

Tags: python, django, oauth, google-api, gdata-api

I am building a social reader Facebook application using Django where I am using Google Data API (Blogger API). But I am unable to deal with the authorization step to use the Google API (currently using ClientLogin under development).

I tried to read the OAuth documentation but couldn't figure out how to proceed. I don't want my users to provide any login credentials for google.. which makes the app completely absurd.

So, can anyone help me on my project and tell me what kind of authorization I should actually use for google API and how ? (I am using `gdata` lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has some packages like `django-facebook` or `django-social-auth` which manage the authentication part of facebook login for you. You could either use these in your project, or look at the code there as a good starting point to learn about FB OAuth implementation.

Comment: what about the Google API authentication?? How do I interact with Google Data API which I am concerned now

Comment: @DennisRitchie I think there are packages for OpenID, also.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque Take up Washington Post Social Reader.. (they might haven't used google api) but the app doesn't ask any user to provide and credentials for google. I want that way!! how could I achieve.. what kind of OAuth I should use

Comment: @DennisRitchie, using OAuth for FB's data is orthogonal from using OAUth for google's data. If you need to access google's user related data, you will have to submit user's credentials to google to allow access. If your application is FB only, then you should use OAuth with FB only.